# Swagger $ref imports file name with field name

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

Good day!

I have some yaml files with documentation to my service.

In fileOne.yaml I need to import a field from fileTwo.yaml

The field definition looks like this:

```
 components:
   schemas:
     someStatus:
      type: string
      enum: [ "status1", "status2" ]
      description: |
        Status of something:
        * `status1` - status1
        * `status2` - status2
```

In fileOne.yaml I import it in this way:

```
components:
  schemas:    
    someBaseField:
      type: object
      title: some title.
      properties:
        importedStatus:
          $ref: 'fileTwo.yaml#/components/schemas/someStatus'
```

Files are in the same folder. The problem is - when I render documentation I see

> importedStatus    fileTwo.yamlsomeStatus

instead of

> importedStatus    someStatus

Can you please help?

Comment: What documentation tool are you using?

Comment: @Software2, SwaggerUI

Answer (score 1):

Swagger UI (and some other tools) can have trouble managing split file definitions. To work around this issue, you can merge your definition into one file before passing it on to Swagger UI.

My preferred tool for this job is [speccy](https://github.com/wework/speccy).

Open the terminal and install `speccy` by running (requires [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)):

`npm install speccy -g`

Then run:

`speccy resolve path/to/spec.yaml -o spec-output.yaml`